# Asus GL702ZC laptop won't even show BIOS

Tags: windows-10, boot, installation, bios

Bad day here.

I blew away my Windows disk by accident (dual boot linux, overly zealous dd.)

So I figured I'd just make a usb stick with Microsofts Win10 on it. No problems.

Laptop won't boot the stick, no matter what I try. Different file system, different creation mechanism, anything.

Read a thing that said I should try enabling CSM in my BIOS. Did so.

Now whenever I hit the power, all I get is a single underscored flashing cursor in the top left of the screen. Nothing else. No BIOS. Nothing.

So I figure I'm properly hosed. Has anyone got any suggestions?

:-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the CMOS. Turn the computer off, unplug the power cable, and remove the CMOS battery. Leave the battery out for a bit so the electricity still present in the motherboard can flush out completely. Resetting the CMOS will restore the BIOS to its default configuration.

While you're waiting, drink a big glass of water and take a 5min walk. When I catch myself in a loop of accidentally breaking things, I step away, clear my head, and come back fresh.

Comment: Yeah. Just about to try that. This thing needs spudgers and hackery to get the battery out though. No idea how to reset the CMOS on it either...

Comment: Page 75 of the laptop's manual shows the 10 screws you'll need to remove to access the majority of the board. You may need more disassembly to access the CMOS.

Comment: Yeah. The manual is remarkably light on CMOS details...

Comment: Were you able to clear the CMOS?